# How to make these buttons not appear as blue links

Tags: html, css

So I'm just trying to create a small website. (Don't worry that's not going
to be the title)
Right now the "Home" "News" "Gallery" and "About us" are not actual buttons that direct to another page. When I do

```
<a href="Mainpage.htm"> Home </a>
```

The button turns into color purple and it is underlined. (I know this is how links are shown) But is there a way that I can make these buttons stay color orange like in the picture without them turning blue and underlined. Thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5yqG.jpg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the styles inline, but the best way to do it is through a css class.

To do it inline:

```
<a href="Mainpage.htm" style="color: #fb3f00; text-decoration: none;">Home</a>
```

To do it through a class:

```
<a href="Mainpage.htm" class="nav-link">Home</a>

a.nav-link:link
{
   color: #fb3f00;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:visited
{
   color: #fb3f00;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:hover
{
   color: #fb3f00;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:active
{
   color: #fb3f00;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

To do it through a class, you need to put the css code in a separate css file and link it in or you can put it in the head of the document. The best practice is to put it in an external css file so it can be used throughout.

If you want the orange to be on every link throughout, just remove the ".nav-link" part of the classes and remove the class="nav-link" from the link tag. This will make all links orange unless you have defined a another class and explicitly applied it to a link tag.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ok this mite be a dumb question. How do I display my code like you guys on this site? The code that I always write is with plain text and not in colors like yours.
Aside from this, I'm using notepad++ to develop the website.Do you guys think this is good?\

Comment: The color coding on StackOverflow is inputted through the editor. When posting your question or answer, there is a button that looks like "{ }". You need to click that and paste your code where it says. Also don't forget to mark the correct answer as the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Mhmmm when I post my answer I can't see the {}

Comment: Also, notepad++ is not a good program to develop a website in. It is good in the fact that you can learn the straight html coding. It would be best if you used a web development software such as Adobe Dreamweaver or Microsoft Visual Studios (Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express is free) for more advanced development.

Comment: Above the textbox you are asking your question in, you should see a series of buttons. They start with Bold, Italic, HyperLink, Blockquote, Code Sample <--- this is the one you need.

Comment: No I know where the question one is. Just not when posting an 
answer. Does this work        {a hre="test.htm"> Test </a>}

Comment: The answer textbox is the same as the question one. Manually putting the {} will not work, you need to press the code button. The answer textbox is located all the way at the bottom of the question and answers.

Answer (score 5):

Using CSS instead of inline styles will work much better:

```
a { 
    color:orange;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

You can also get fancier and have the underline appear when you hover:

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

This can help improve user experience (UX), though if the links are in the header it may be naturally apparent that they are links. (UX design is more complex than this of course, because you have to consider things like touchscreen users that have no "hover". :) )

Comment: Oh I was doing it in HTML not in CSS
I'll change it to stylesheet

Comment: @davidcamacho You absolutely should use CSS. HTML in-line styles have been obsolete for a decade, all pro shops use CSS (and increasingly things like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/))

Comment: You should always use a stylesheet, as inline css is a lot less powerful, and you can specify classes/ids to style HTML elements specifically.

Comment: You can get away with simply selecting `a`, and it'll force the rule for all states, including `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active`; I think this may be due to specificity rules.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that if you have an :hover pseudo class, pair it with a matching :focus pseudoclass, in order to be friendly to users who rely on keyboard navigation. e.g. a:hover, a:focus { text-decoration: underline;}

Answer (score 3):

All links come with different states so if you want them to stay with just one color you can modify all the states together like so:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color: orange }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using CSS.
to set this in your code right at the end of the head-section

```
    <style TYPE="text/css">

   a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color: #ff8080;
       text-decoration: none;
     }

    </style>
```

and change the #ff8080 in your color

Comment: Meanwhile in my html sheet I would have 
<a href="Maingpage.htm">Home</a> <a href="Mainpage.htm"> Gallery </a>

And so on?

Answer (score 0):

I have the perfect solution for you!

I'm copying and pasting straight from my code. make it relevant to you. This definitely works for what you are trying to achieve.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
a:link { color:#ffffff; text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { color:#33348e; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#91ac48; text-decoration: none; }
a:active { color:#7476b4; text-decoration: underline; }
</style> <a href="/shop">Order Now</a>
```